# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core vs System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: dynamic-linq

What is the difference between System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and System.Linq.Dynamic? I am currently using System.Linq.Dynamic and it does not contain support for **Select** and **SelectMany** (among other extension methods). Does System.Linq.Dynamic.Core support these methods?

Answer (score 18):

**System.Linq.Dynamic.Core** is more up to date and has more functionality and does also support NET Core / NETStandard (besides net35, net40 and net45 and up)

**SelectMany** is indeed supported.

For more information see the [github](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) page and browse the examples, unit-tests and help page.

Note:
I'm the maintainer from this project.

Comment: Could I ask If there are some video tutorials or books about how to write the `dynamic linq`, I face a lot of troubles to understand the documentation :(

Comment: For more documentation and example code: see https://dynamic-linq.net/overview

Answer (score 3):

See  description on github:

1. [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)
2. [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

System.Linq.Dynamic is the Microsoft assembly for the .Net 4.0 Dynamic language functionality.
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core is a .NET Core port of the the Microsoft assembly for the .Net 4.0 Dynamic language functionality

Comment: Looking at the [issue list](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues) for `System.Linq.Dynamic` it's clear that it is not currently being maintained/updated. `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` is a fork that is being actively developed (it works with standard .NET as well as .NET Core)