# String concatenation in dynamic-linq Select

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to return a new column that is the concatenation of `id` and `name`, with a hyphen inbeween, using dynamic-linq:

```
query.Select("new(id, name, id & " - " & name As idName")
```

But, I'm failing even to get simple concatenation working, even without the hyphen:

```
query.Select("new(id, name, id & name As idName")
```

This raises `System.NotSupportedException`

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String
>   Concat(System.Object, System.Object) method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Is there any way around this, and if so, how would I also add the quoted section `" - "` to the expression in a way that dynamic-linq can interpret, also I'd like `id` and `name` to be variables as these change depending on the user's selection?

NOTE:

- I'm using dynamic-linq because the names of the columns I want to concatenate vary, based on user selection, plus I'm already using dynamic-linq for a `Where` clause).
- The `id` and `name` columns are both of type string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right this should work.

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Dim col1 = "id"
Dim col2 = "name"

Dim results = query.Select($"new({col1} as {col1},
                                 {col2} as {col2},
                                 {col1} & "" - "" & {col2} as {col1}_{col2})")
```

There are maybe other ways, but you still will be only querying once the db, so it should be no problem I think.

Hope it helps...

Comment: this is close, but the names of my columns can vary. Is there any way that `.Id`, `.Name` and `.IdName` can also be changed dynamically based on the user's selection? (Can I somehow have interpolated strings on the left-hand side of the Anonymous Type)?

Comment: What type is your query object? Are you using EF?

Comment: Yes, it's an EF6 IQueryable. I'm using `Imports System.Linq.Dynamic` to get the `Select` overload that allows me to use a String as a selector. The error indicates that LINQ to Entities is being used, but I'm not sure that should make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

The [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) NuGet package lists https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic as the project page. 
 Here, examples from Scott Guthrie's [original 2008 blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) on dynamic LINQ were being transferred over to the GitHub project's [wiki](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki), and the documentation was being extended.

However, looking through the [issues list](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues), the repository appears to be dead/dying ([discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659865/system-linq-dynamic-core-vs-system-linq-dynamic)). Currently, the most active [fork](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)/[NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) appears to be System.Linq.Dynamic.Core (which support .NET standard as well as .NET Core).

The documentation and examples in the original `System.Linq.Dynamic` are currently more extensive, but both wikis have a section on [dynamic expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) and the [expression language](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#expression-language) which include a section on operators. This includes concatenation:

> x & y String concatenation. Operands may be of any type.

**In my tests, concatenation works if you switch from the `System.Linq.Dynamic` NuGet package to the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` package (you don't have to be using .NET Core, it works with other versions of .NET as well).**

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

query.Select("new(id & name As id_name)")
```

Comment: Correct, you can use + or & when concatenating strings.
See this unit test : https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/597127e53fc7f3ca0654a8ac105e9b98d690677b/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/ExpressionTests.cs#L1385